# How to open WebBrowser control in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webbrowser-control

How can I open WebBrowser controller in visual Studio Browser?

**My code**

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
wb.Show();
```

I use this code but I can't open the browser in visual studio 2010

Comment: Where is this code? A control needs to be on a form.

Comment: This controll is in form

Comment: How would you display any other control?

Comment: My form contain only on button for showing webbrowser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajay, you need to add the control to form. Do like this:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Location = //suitably.
Controls.Add(wb);
wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

But if you have already added web browser from the designer to your form, then you need not instantiate a new instance of browser in the code. Instead you just do:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
```

There is no need of `.Show()` unless you have hidden it previously.

Comment: But I can't see any browser open in visual studio.

If I use  Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
it open internet explorer,but I don't like this.
 I want to open visual studio browser

Comment: See, to see it in visual studio form designer, you should drag and drop the control from the tool box to your form. Just the same as how u would add a button or any other control.

Comment: What do you mean by not in visual studio? you can have a browser control on your form, not in visual studio itself. To have the browser on your form, add it. Web browser is listed under common controls in tool box or see under all controls in tool box. And then when you run the program, ask it navigate to the site u prefer using the `Navigate()` call.

Comment: I add one webBrowser controller from toolbox and just navigate it to web page i.e. www.google.com

Comment: So I assume mine is the right answer ;) glad could be of help.. cheers
(call it control, not controller)

Answer (score 1):

Drag and Drop WebBrowser control from tool box to your form. 
use this code to nevigate

```
WebBrowser1.Nevigate("http://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser class is an embedded windows forms control.  If you are looking to automate Internet Explorer you need to either use Process.Start or MSHTML.

Comment: If I want to open it in visual studio browser so what can I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to open a web page in the Visual Studio IDE itself ? If so you have to write an extension to Visual studio, or a macro or an AddIn depending on your need.

Use the IVsWebBrowsingService interface to do that

```
var service = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsWebBrowsingService)) as IVsWebBrowsingService;
IVsWindowFrame pFrame = null;
var filePath = @"file:///C:/dell/foo.html";
service.Navigate(filePath, (uint)__VSWBNAVIGATEFLAGS.VSNWB_WebURLOnly, out pFrame);
pFrame.Show();
```

The above code should be wrote inside a visual studio addin or extension.